# C++ conditional storage allocation for object caused by scope

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, initialization

Currently I'm reading `Think in C++`.

I'm confused about the **conditional storage allocation for an object**.

As the code below, the `goto` and `switch` generate *warning or an error*.

But `if-else` works fine, which is conditionally passed through during execution.

So why there is no warning or error for `if-else`?

```
/* crosses initializaion error */  
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X {
public:
    X();
};
X::X() {}

void f(int i) {
    if (i > 2) {
       X x1;
    } else {
       X x2; // why conditionally executed works fine?
    }
    if (i > 2) {
        goto jjump1;
    }
    //X x3;  // error coused by goto
    {X x3; //works fine}
jjump1:
    X x4;
    switch(i) {
      // case 1:    X x5; break;
     //case 2:  X x6; break; // error coused by switch
       {case 1: X x5; break;}
       {case 2: X x6; break;}//  solved

    }
 }
int main() {
    f(1);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

`C++ doing so is to guarantee that an object cannot be created unless it is also initialized.` But in the case of `if-else` how can both part of it be initialized as only one part of it will be go through?

As the C++ is following the practice in C of **allocating the storage for a scope at the opening brace of that scope.**

Here is my thought(I don't know what's wrong..):

But it's the same for `switch` and `goto`, only the token case need to be initialized but there is crosses initialization error. The `if-else` and `switch` both obey `initializing the token branch only.`

At last, I figured out the key word is `scope`. **As the C++ is following the practice in C of allocating the storage for a scope at the opening brace of that scope.** So the *A program that jumps87 from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer* rule ensure that *variables are initialized once allocated*.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why are you using `goto`? Why are you declaring objects in a code block and throwing them away? Why does the function `f` do nothing?

Comment: I'm doing an experiment to figure out some detail about storage allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not allowed to jump past the declaration of a variable unless it is scalar or it has a trivial default constructor, this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.7`:

> > It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps<sup>87</sup> from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

In the case of the *switch* one way to avoid this problem would be to create a scope using `{}` at each label like this:

```
switch(i)
{
   case 1: { X x5;  break; }
   case 2: { X x6;  break; }
}
```

Comment: What I'm asking is why the `if-else` works fine? Isn't it some kind of  jump through?

Comment: @luoluo *if* is not a jump statement. The jump statements are `break`, `continue`, `return` and `goto` which are covered in section `6.6. Jump Statements`. The `if` statement is classified as a *selection statement*. The *body* of the *if* will have it's own scope and any variables declared in that local scope will not exist outside of it.

Comment: But When I deleted the `break` in `switch`, there is still a `crosses initialization` error. Does this mean that `switch` belongs to `Jump statements` or may be converted to something like that?

Comment: @luoluo it is because there is only one scope that covers all of the *case* labels, you can get around this in a *switch* by using `{}` at each label. I will update my answer.

Comment: Then what's the benefit of this?

Comment: @luoluo that is a broad question, they are techniques. Using them effectively though and recognizing when to use them takes a long time to master. Although in general, except in specialized cases like the Linux kernel you would avoid using *goto* and generally you would declare variables before the *switch* statement.

Comment: But in the case of if-else how can both part of it be initialized as only one part of it will be go through?

Comment: @luoluo You answered your own question: since only one branch will be taken per call to `f`, only one initialization needs to be taken account for.

Comment: But it's the same for switch, only the token case need to be initialized but there is `crosses initialization` error. The `if-else` and `switch` seem both obey `initialize the token branch`.