# Why does GCC give me the -Wjump-misses-init warning?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have a piece of code that compiles fine when I write it in this form (with the `-Wjump-misses-init` flag):

```
int some_function(void) {

        ...

        if (is_error)
                goto error;

        int a;

        a = 1;

        return a;

error:
        return 666;
}
```

But when I write the same function in this form I get the below warning when I compile (:

```
int some_function(void) {

        ...

        if (is_error)
                goto error;

        int a = 1;

        return a;

error:
        return 666;
}

test.c: In function 'some_function':
test.c:15:17: warning: jump skips variable initialization [-Wjump-misses-init]
test.c:21:1: note: label 'error' defined here
test.c:17:13: note: 'a' declared here
```

Why does GCC give me that warning when I declare and initialize `a` on the same line? Seems a bit odd to me? These examples are nonsensical but I'm afraid I'm not at liberty to divulge the real code snippet. I am running GCC 4.7.2 on Debian Wheezy 7.3.

EDIT: void typo

Comment: In C++ you [are not allowed to jump past a declaration with initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963288/c-conditional-storage-allocation-for-object-caused-by-scope/20963326#20963326) but I am having trouble finding the same statement in C99.

Comment: I wonder if the error hold with different optimization flags. Or if the assembly differs. Maybe in one case the order of operations is slightly different. It's just a wild guess though.

Comment: Also, `int void` looks a typo.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Oh, ok I edited away this part out of my comment.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour nope I compile with gcc <warning flags> test.c

Comment: @PascalCuoq indeed, I just discovered that, I am always learning new nooks and crannies.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821663/c99-goto-past-initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *C++* you are not allowed to [bypasses declarations with initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963288/c-conditional-storage-allocation-for-object-caused-by-scope/20963326#20963326) but it seems to be allowed in *C99*. You can have `gcc`  warn you about if you either use `-Wjump-misses-init` or `-Wc++-compat`. This is covered in the `gcc` docs section  [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and says:

> Warn if a goto statement or a switch statement jumps forward across the initialization of a variable, or jumps backward to a label after the variable has been initialized. This only warns about variables that are initialized when they are declared. This warning is only supported for C and Objective-C; in C++ this sort of branch is an error in any case.
>
> -Wjump-misses-init is included in -Wc++-compat. It can be disabled with the -Wno-jump-misses-init option.

Note, this also applies to declarations inside a *switch* statement. One way to work around this is to create a new scope using `{}`.

In the *Annex I* the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) suggests this as warning, it says:

> An implementation may generate warnings in many situations, none of which are
> specified as part of this International Standard. The following are a few of the more
> common situations.

and includes the following bullet:

> A block with initialization of an object that has automatic storage duration is jumped
> into (6.2.4).

Comment: Interesting, `-Wjump-misses-init` isn't in `-Wc++-compat` for my version of gcc (4.8.1, Ubuntu 12.04).  Has it been removed?

Comment: @ecatmur hmmm, seems to be so in `4.8` although `4.7` still has it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use the `a` variable after jumping to the `error:` label, its value would be indeterminate (6.2.4p6); this is potentially confusing, which is why gcc warns about it.  (It is also illegal in C++.)

To avoid the warning and still use declaration-initialization, you can wrap code in a block:

```
int some_function(void) {
    {
        ...

        if (is_error)
                goto error;

        int a = 1;

        return a;
    }
error:
    return 666;
}
```

In this case, you would need to declare outside the block any variables that you use after the `error:` label.